# how to connect and get data from scale machine with tcp client side javascript

Tags: tcpclient

I need some data which was stored in a scale machine [machine have some ip address (http:122.168.1.12:30)]. i want to How to establish a TCP connection from a web browser to machine (client side) . here i want to connect machine with tcp/ip address, read and display that data in browser with click event. can any one please let me know how to do this using node js or javascript. in web browser 
[image]

Comment: you might need to go with websockets

Comment: i read some articles websocket need server. here i have problem with firewall. my requirement only read data from machine and display it in browser with tcp connection (client side only)